# How to filter data base on average price in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to create a search for my website with filter. When a person search for a room by price I want to return rooms base on average price. The average price is calculated like this:
‍‍‍‍‍`(avg(room_calendar_prices) + night(night_price)) / 2`

My Elasticsearch data is something like this:

```
{
    "_index" : "myindex",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "Xs6BNHgBHuRzPOCF2v-d",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "total_score" : 0.0,
      "id" : 1205975,
      "user_id" : 10264,
      "property_type" : 1,
      "room_type" : 3,
      "room_area" : 91,
      "floors" : 8,
      "accommodates" : 8,
      "extra_accommodates" : 18,
      "status" : "Listed",
      "name" : "Great room in Paris",
      "summary" : "",
      "created_at" : "2021-03-01 13:03:57",
      "updated_at" : "2021-03-14 08:44:08",
      "mode_person" : 0,
      "night" : 3602649,
      "cleaning" : 185432,
      "additional_guest" : 4803704,
      "weekend" : 3922605,
      "minimum_stay" : 37,
      "maximum_stay" : 30,
      "currency_code" : "USD",
      "holiday" : 4884994,
      "room_calendar_blocks" : [ ],
      "room_discounts" : [
        {
          "id" : 1003021,
          "room_id" : 1205975,
          "discount_type" : null,
          "started_at" : "2021-03-09 00:00:00",
          "finished_at" : "2021-03-25 00:00:00",
          "min_amount" : "0.00",
          "max_amount" : "0.00",
          "night_percent" : 44,
          "night_amount" : "0.00",
          "weekend_percent" : 44,
          "weekend_amount" : "0.00",
          "holiday_percent" : 44,
          "holiday_amount" : "0.00",
          "use_coupon_code" : 1,
          "is_active" : 1,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-14 10:19:57",
          "updated_at" : "2021-03-14 10:19:57",
          "deleted_at" : null
        }
      ],
      "rooms_price_rules" : [
        {
          "id" : 1190948,
          "room_id" : 1205975,
          "type" : "length_of_stay",
          "period" : 7,
          "discount" : 8
        }
      ],
      "room_calendar_prices" : [
        {
          "id" : 326787,
          "room_id" : 1205975,
          "started_at" : "2021-03-26",
          "finished_at" : "2021-03-26",
          "price" : 653060.0,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-13 18:15:44",
          "updated_at" : "2021-03-13 18:15:44"
        },
        {
          "id" : 303942,
          "room_id" : 1205975,
          "started_at" : "2021-04-04",
          "finished_at" : "2021-04-04",
          "price" : 3407859.0,
          "created_at" : "2021-03-13 18:15:34",
          "updated_at" : "2021-03-13 18:15:34"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I need to calculate average price like I said and then filter rooms base on average price ranges.
For example users will ask for rooms with price between 1000 and 1200 per night.
Is it possible in Elasticsearch?
I wrote a query and trying to do this but I can't calculate the average.
My incomplete query is something like this:

```
    GET /myindex/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "night",
    "room_calendar_prices.started_at",
    "room_calendar_prices.finished_at",
    "room_calendar_prices.price"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "room_calendar_prices",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "room_calendar_prices.finished_at": {
                  "gte": "2021-04-03",
                  "lte": "2021-04-10"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "room_calendar_prices",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "room_calendar_prices.started_at": {
                  "gte": "2021-04-03",
                  "lte": "2021-04-10"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupby": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 20,
        "sources": [
          {
            "room_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "missing_bucket": true,
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "median_price": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "room_calendar_prices"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "condition": {
              "range": {
                "field": "room_calendar_prices.started_at",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "from": "2021-04-02",
                    "to": "2021-04-11"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "aggs": {
                "calculated_price": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "room_calendar_prices.price"
                  }
                },
                "total_average_price": {
                  "bucket_script": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "calculted_avg_price": "calculated_price"
                    },
                    "script": "params.calculted_avg_price /  1000"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick recommendation: if you expect this query to be used very often, you shouldn't calculate the average price at query time (significant impact on performance), but rather calculate it at indexing time (create/update) and store the result in a field.

Comment: Second sentence — what does `night(night_price)` mean?

Comment: @JoeSorocin That is, the price that the customer has to pay for each night's stay

Comment: @glenacota I can't do that, because I don't know what price range the customer want to select in filter time.